# Python: trouble converting string into date

Tags: python, datetime

I am somewhat new to Python and have a seemingly simple question.

I have a python script that interacts with an API (RHN Satellite if you're curious). This API returns a date in the form of a string and it always trims leading 0's. For example, 6/1/13 or 10/9/12. I need to convert this string to a date and determine the day of the year it is.

Here is what I know:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
print today.strftime('%j')
```

...will return today's day of year (175). This works fine for a datetime object but I am having trouble converting the string given by the API to an actual date. If I use:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(var, '%m/%d/$y')
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: time data '5/2/13' does not match format '%m/%d/$y'
```

I'm guessing because it's expecting leading 0's ? How do I get around this?

In the end, I am trying to subtract the variable date given from the current date but I can't do that until I convert the string.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: May be `%y` instead of `$y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a typo, use `%y` instead of `$y`:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(var, '%m/%d/%y')
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me, provided you change `$y` to `%y` in the format code.

Comment: I'm an idiot. You are correct. That's what i get for not getting up and walking away from it for a few minutes. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Correct the `$y` to `%y` and I'd use `format` instead of `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
print format(datetime.strptime('5/2/13', '%m/%d/%y'), '%j')
```